# Format money to currency in asp.net mvc c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have one field in database, store price of my products. Its datatype is money and I want to format it like : 8.20, 10.00, and 100,00.00
This is my code :

```
$<%: string.Format("{0:00.00}", price)%>
```

But the output is not like what I want, anyone have any idea about that? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the currency format (`0:C`):

```
<%: string.Format("{0:C}", price) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for:

```
  $<%: string.Format("{0:#0.00}", price)%>
```

This will skip the leading 0 for numbers under 10.

See [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%: string.Format("{0:N2}", price) %>
```